# How do I convert a GEKKO returned integer back to a python recognizable integer?

Tags: gekko

The function **intpolatn** receives the integer variable **u_hub_next** from a `GEKKO` maximized objective function. **intpolatn** is just meant to `check` if the integer falls between `windvel[0] and windvel[1]` and succeeding `elif statements`, and then return the appropriate list, depending on which `elif condition` satisfies the value of **u_hub_next**. However, `GEKKO` keeps throwing the error **TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()** at the `if` conditional, and hence the code cannot proceed to the remainder of the python code. A snippet of the code is given below without succeeding `elif` statements and without the `gekko` section: I'd appreciate any guidance.

```
def intpolatn(u_hub_next):
    windvel = np.array([0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 14])
    thrust_coeff = np.array([0, 0.9, 0.9, 0.7, 0.83, 0.39])
    # print(u_hub_next)
    if windvel[0] <= u_hub_next < windvel[1]:
        m = 0
        c_t = 0
        axial = 0
        p_u = check_p_u(u_hub_next) 
        u_hub_next = 0
        return [u_hub_next, c_t, axial, p_u]
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the value of `u_hub_next` with:

```py
uhn = u_hub_next.value[0]
```

The value is a `float` type so use `int(uhn)` to convert it to an integer type or one of the [Numpy integer types](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html) for even more control.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still doesn't solve the problem. In fact, if I print u_hub_next immediately before the if statement, where it is being commented out, it outputs an integer value. Too bad I cannot reproduce the error here, since it is a collection of scripts that call each other. It used to run without the error but suddenly started misbehaving after I changed the value of axi_max in this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67196304/the-code-below-continues-to-give-the-error-error-equation-definition-equatio/67200354#67200354

Comment: If that function is part of the optimization problem (not just an output after the solution is finished) then you should use the `m.if3()` or `m.if2()` function. If you just need the output of `u_hub_next` then `int(u_hub_next.value[0])` should work. Maybe try it with a simple problem such as with one of these https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/IntegerBinaryVariables to verify that you can convert a Gekko variable into a Python `int` type.

Comment: The function works with the output variables from GEKKO, and unfortunately, `int(u_hub_next.value[0])` still doesn't work. Now, I have the output variables from my question in -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67196304/why-does-the-code-terminate-with-a-solution-not-found-error-and-exit-converg but cannot use the output to proceed with the remainder of the system model.

Comment: Could you let us know what `int(u_hub_next.value[0])` produces? What isn't working? If the solver did not find a successful solution, it may not have a value.

Comment: The solver found a solution and I needed to use the values of the optimized variables outside the gekko environment to test an if-else condition. Python could not recognize the gekko output as integers and so the if-else test could not go through. It has been resolve though. I had to convert the gekko returned list to an array. I suppose the trick is to do some form of conversion; either to a numpy array, a dictionary, a pandas dataframe or whatever works for the scenario, whenever you want to do such conditional tests outside gekko using gekko generated output. Thank you! @John Hedengren